# Microservice Architecture using RabbitMQ or SignalR

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, signalr, microservices

Migration from a Monolith to a Microservice architecture. I'm having a hard time understanding the architeture so I'd need your feedbacks on the questions asked below.

QUESTIONS:

- Will a dependent API `API-two` wait for the response from the caller `API-One` in Synchronous Microservice Architecture.
- Or if we pass client's details over to `API-Two` via `Api-One`, can `API-Two` directly connect to the client with a response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**if you want use SIGNAL-R**

- the client request for the pdf to API-1
- the API-1 service gather the require data from database and publish to the BUS channel (RabbitMQ channel) including the client-user identification data (as configured in signal-R) where the API two is listening to consume. at this point the client is acknowledged by response (the api and the client become idle and not waiting just ensure the event from here is fired).
- the API-2 receives and consumes the event with data and generates pdf.
- then api-2 after generating the pdf successfully calls signal-R service and trigger to send back the data to the client-user who requested or the signal-R notifies the client-user with error message.

> I think SignalR shouldn't be used in this scenario as it's more to
> sendiing responses from server to multiple clients

no the signal-R is also used to send push notification to specific user with specific data. like notifications in any user-panel that could be notifies a group of users or specific user or chat application.

**if you can persist pdf some where**

- the client request for the pdf to API-1
- the API-1 service gather the require data from database and publish to the BUS channel (RabbitMQ channel) including the client-user identification data where the API two is listening to consume. at this point the client is acknowledged by response (the api and the client become idle and not waiting just ensure the event from here is fired).
- the API-2 receives and consumes the event with data and generates pdf.
- the API-2 may persist the pdf with appropriate data (meta data eg:user data)
- user-client can check his panel (for example table of his pdfs) and download by requesting the api-2 who is now responsible for it (or any service)

**if you can persist data some where**

- the client request for the pdf to API-1
- the API-1 service gather the require data from database and publish to the BUS channel (RabbitMQ channel) including the client-user identification data where the API two is listening to consume. at this point the client is acknowledged by response (the api and the client become idle and not waiting just ensure the event from here is fired).
- the API-2 receives and consumes the event with data and **generates for example report DATA or any data that should be in the pdf**.
- the API-2 may persist the generated-data with appropriate meta data eg:user data
- user-client can check his panel (for example table of his pdfs) request api-2 to get the appropriate generated-data and the the client-app itself will generate pdf from the given response data.

when it comes to event-driven base communication you have in mind that the fault may happen and you need to control it since the api one is already acknowledged and dont have any idea ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)).

Comment: The idea if that the ```API-Two``` will be responsible to generate base64 and send back to client. And the Client Application will convert the base64 to pdf. One thing which confuses me is the ```User-Client```. What is this?

Comment: I mean client app with identified user logged in. Sorry if its brought douts.

Comment: Okay. However if suppose 1000 users are using the service and if ```RabbitMQ``` uses queuing system, does that mean the 1000th user's request will be processed last and there will be a delay since ```RabbitMQ``` follows FIFO.

Comment: this question is the nice one so pushed me forward about scaling rabbitmq. first you scale the services (that is obvious) eg: 3 instances of api-2 and also scaling the rabbitmq bus exchange which can be achieve by deferent ways that still i am looking for. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding this is one of the ways. take a look at it. also i think it is good idea to ask this question to see what others do.